# Fetching cells having checkmark accessory

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview

I am working with the table view. I added the checkmark Accessory on the first tap of the screen and removed this checkmark on the second tap. I added few ckeckmarks on the cells of table view. Now i want that the labels of the cells having the checkmarks should be displayed on the NSlog.
 please help me out regarding this issue. Any help will be much appriciable.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (tableView.tag == 0)
    {
        return [celltitles count];
    }
    else
    {
    return 7;
    }
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    if (tableView.tag == 0)
    {

        cell.textLabel.text = [celltitles objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        if (indexPath.row == 0)
        {
            habitname = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(150, 0, 150, 50)];
            habitname.placeholder = @"Habit Name";
            habitname.delegate= self;
            [cell addSubview:habitname];
        }
                else if (indexPath.row == 1)
        {
            timelbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 0, 220, 50)];
            timelbl.text = @"OFF";
            timelbl.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
            [cell addSubview:timelbl];

            timetitlelbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 50)];
            timetitlelbl.text = @"Alert";
            timetitlelbl.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
            [cell addSubview:timetitlelbl];

            toggleswitch = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(250, 5, 50, 60)];
            toggleswitch.on = NO;
            [toggleswitch addTarget:self action:@selector(toggleSwitch) forControlEvents:(UIControlEventValueChanged | UIControlEventTouchDragInside)];
            [cell addSubview:toggleswitch];

        }
    }
    else if (tableView.tag == 1)
    {
        cell.textLabel.text = [daysarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    }

    return cell;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {



        if (indexPath.row == 1)
        {
            if (toggleswitch.on)
            {
                [self datepickershown:timelbl.text animated:YES];

            if (self.datePickerIsShowing)
            {
                //[self datepickershown];
                //[self hideDatePickerCell];
                [dscptxt resignFirstResponder];
            }
            else
            {
                [dscptxt resignFirstResponder];
                [self.timelbl resignFirstResponder];
                [self showDatePickerCell];
            }
        }
        else
        {
        timelbl.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
        }
    }
else if (indexPath.row > 2 && indexPath.row <10)
{
   NSLog(@"I am Selectin the row");


    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        if (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone)
        {
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;

        }
        else if (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark)
        {
           // NSLog(@"Selected Accessory Is %d",cell.accessoryType);
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        }
    }

    [self.tableview deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}

- (void)savedata:(id)sender
{
}
```

Above is the code which i am using and on the save action i want the log.

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20423960/fetching-the-checkmarked-cells-label. I've put my answer there, by the way.

Answer (score 1):

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone)
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        [markedArray addObject:indexPath.row];
    }
    else if (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark)
    {
       // NSLog(@"Selected Accessory Is %d",cell.accessoryType);
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        [markedArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
} 
- (void)savedata:(id)sender
  {
    //write here your code to save to database
    for(int i=0; i<markedArray.count; i++)
        NSLog@"saved labels are %@",[celltitles objectAtIndex:[markedArray      objectAtIndex:i]];
   }
```

Try this :)

Comment: where should i add this method??

Comment: first one when you marked a row checked. And second when you want to log. That is the reason we are asking to post your code

Answer (score 0):

You can get all selected indexPaths from below method.

```
NSArray *selectedIndexPaths = [self.Yourtableview indexPathsForSelectedRows];
```

after getting this selected index array. You can get title of cell using indexPath.row property.

Comment: Where are you calling this method?

Comment: actually i want to save these cell labels in the database on the click of button. So i am calling this method on that click....

Answer (score 0):

You also can store selected objects (objects from where you show data in table) in additional array. 
Just add/remove data-object to array in didSelectRow method and you will have table state data in any time later.

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend you to use the checkmark approach to find out the selected cells

Try this:

1. Create a NSMutableArray named 'selectedCells' (or something else). It can either be a property or an instance variable.
2. Instantiate it in `-viewDidLoad` method.
3. In bottom your `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath` method add this code.

   if([selectedCells containsObject:@(indexPath.row)]){
       cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
   }else{
         cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
   }
4. In your `-tableView:didSelectRowForIndexPath:` method call:

   if([selectedCells containsObject:@(indexPath.row)]){
       [selectedCells removeObject:@(indexPath.row)];
   }else{
       [selectedCells addObject:@(indexPath.row)];
   }

Using this way you always have the info for the selected cell (or cells having checkmarks) in 'selectedCells'