# Fetching the checkmarked cell's label

Tags: ios, iphone, tableview

I am working with the table view. I added the checkmark Accessory on the first tap of the screen and removed this checkmark on the second tap. I added few ckeckmarks on the cells of table view. Now i want that the labels of the cells having the checkmarks should be displayed on the NSlog.
 please help me out regarding this issue. Any help will be much appriciable.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (tableView.tag == 0)
    {
        return [celltitles count];
    }
    else
    {
    return 7;
    }
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    if (tableView.tag == 0)
    {
        cell.textLabel.text = [celltitles objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        if (indexPath.row == 0)
        {
            habitname = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(150, 0, 150, 50)];
            habitname.placeholder = @"Habit Name";
            habitname.delegate= self;
            [cell addSubview:habitname];
        }
                else if (indexPath.row == 1)
        {
            timelbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 0, 220, 50)];
            timelbl.text = @"OFF";
            timelbl.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
            [cell addSubview:timelbl];

            timetitlelbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 50)];
            timetitlelbl.text = @"Alert";
            timetitlelbl.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
            [cell addSubview:timetitlelbl];

            toggleswitch = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(250, 5, 50, 60)];
            toggleswitch.on = NO;
            [toggleswitch addTarget:self action:@selector(toggleSwitch) forControlEvents:(UIControlEventValueChanged | UIControlEventTouchDragInside)];
            [cell addSubview:toggleswitch];

        }
    }
    else if (tableView.tag == 1)
    {
        cell.textLabel.text = [daysarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    }

    return cell;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    if (indexPath.row == 1)
    {
        if (toggleswitch.on)
        {
            [self datepickershown:timelbl.text animated:YES];

            if (self.datePickerIsShowing)
            {
                //[self datepickershown];
                //[self hideDatePickerCell];
                [dscptxt resignFirstResponder];
            }
            else
            {
                [dscptxt resignFirstResponder];
                [self.timelbl resignFirstResponder];
                [self showDatePickerCell];
            }
        }
        else
        {
            timelbl.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
        }

    }
    else if (indexPath.row > 2 && indexPath.row <10)
    {
        NSLog(@"I am Selectin the row");

        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        if (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone)
        {
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;

        }
        else if (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark)
        {
           // NSLog(@"Selected Accessory Is %d",cell.accessoryType);
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        }
    }

    [self.tableview deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}

- (void)savedata:(id)sender
{
}
```

Above is the code which i am using and on the save action i want the log.

Comment: Maintain an array to hold the check marked indexpath.row, add the index path.row to the array when ever you checks a new row, and remove that index path.row when you are unchecking the row from the array.

Comment: You should probably [check this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5959950/iphone-uitableview-cellaccessory-checkmark).

Answer (score 3):

Don't use the `UITableView` to store your data. Cells are reused, so that's **not** a reliable way to detect which items you have selected.

You could store whether an item is selected in an array, for instance. Then in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` determine if the checkmark should be displayed. In `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` you update the model (your array) and request a reload for the specific cell.

This will result in a better MVC separation.

**EDIT**: added example for the `UITableView` stuff

```
// for this example we'll be storing NSIndexPath objects in our Model
// you might want to use a @property for this
NSMutableSet *model = [NSMutableSet set];


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    ...

    if([model containsObject:indexPath]) {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    } 
    else {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }

    ... 
}


-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    ...

    // update the model
    if([model containsObject:indexPath]) {
        [model removeObject:indexPath];
    } 
    else {
        [model addObject:indexPath];
    }

    // request reload of selected cell
    [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

    ...

}
```

Now it should be fairly easy to log all selected items, without having to use the `UITableView`: it's all in your model now!

Comment: A view (mVc) is for displaying data, not storing it. By only setting the Checkmark on a cell, you're basically storing data in your view. You shouldn't: store data in the model (Mvc). I'll update my answer with some code.

Comment: ok i am getting the output and seems to be preety well bt i am not getting the desired output...... output which i am getting with this code is somwwhat like this.:-                                                 "<NSIndexPath: 0xc000000000018016> {length = 2, path = 0 - 3}",
    "<NSIndexPath: 0xc000000000020016> {length = 2, path = 0 - 4}",
    "<NSIndexPath: 0xc000000000028016> {length = 2, path = 0 - 5}",
    "<NSIndexPath: 0xc000000000030016> {length = 2, path = 0 - 6}", whereas i want the the label in my output.....

Comment: That's because you're probably logging the content of the model array and that's an NSIndexPath. Get the title from your cell titles array. Somehing like: `for(NSIndexPath *indexPath in model) { NSLog(celltitles[indexPath.Row]); }`

Answer (score 0):

Make a for loop:

```
NSMutableArray *mutArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for(i = 0;i <= self.rowCount-1;i++)
 {

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0]];

if (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark)
{
           [mutArray addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0]];
 }

}
NSLog(@"Array: %@", mutArray);
```

Comment: There where you want to access your selected cells.

Comment: u mean on the action where i want the nslog?? and what should be the rowcount??